# Verify the existence of a word in an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I searched a bit, but couldn't find an answer to this (probably very simple) question.

I have an NSString, and I'd like to check if it contains a word. Something like this:

```
NSString *sentence = @"The quick brown fox";
NSString *word = @"quack";
if ([sentence containsWord:word]) {
    NSLog(@"Yes it does contain that word");
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following should work:

```
NSString *sentence = @"The quick brown fox";
NSString *word = @"quack";
if ([sentence rangeOfString:word].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Yes it does contain that word");
}
```

It uses `rangeOfString:` to return an `NSRange` structure, indicating the location of the word, if it can't find it `NSRange.location` will be equal to `NSNotFound`.

Comment: thats not a correct answer, as this will match also part-matches, not words, like "Hi welcome" for "wel" you would return -> Yes it does contain that word but thats not true