# How can I find whether an exact sub string is present or not in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How can I find whether an exact `substring` is present or not in `NSString`.

Currently assume a `string "1000 * RoomTemperature"` and I want to check whether "RoomTemperature" is present or not.

`["1000 * RoomTemperature" rangeOfString:"RoomTemperature"].location != NSNotFound`  this will give me `TRUE`. 
But if I check `["1000 * RoomTemperature" rangeOfString:"Temperature"].location != NSNotFound`. This will also return me `TRUE`.

My requirement is to get `FALSE` for the second scenario. Please help me out to get a solution.

Comment: What is your definition of "exact" substring?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield : RoomTemperature and Temperature are substrings for string "1000 * RoomTemperature".What I mean by exact substring in this string is RoomTemperature

Comment: What if the string contains no spaces, e.g. `@"1000*RoomTemperature"`?  Then is `RoomTemperature` an “exact” substring?

Comment: Edit your question to define **in detail** what separates an ”exact substring” from surrounding characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verify the existence of a word in an NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581916/verify-the-existence-of-a-word-in-an-nsstring)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code. It will return true only if the word exist and false if not exist

> ```
> NSString *str =  @"1000 * RoomTemperature";
> NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
> return [array containsObject:@"RoomTemperature"];
> ```

Comment: [str componentsSeparatedByString:str]; must be [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; or [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"];