# Check a string for banned words

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, string, nsarray

I have some code that creates a string 6 characters long of random alphanumerics ("a key").

ex: "AJ4L3I"

I want to make sure these keys never contain terms that I can add to an array.

`NSArray *bannedTerms = @[@"666", @"ass", @"hell", //etc., nil];`

How can I check if an NSString like "HJ666P" contains a term in my bannedTerms NSArray or NSMutableArray.

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verify the existence of a word in an NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581916/verify-the-existence-of-a-word-in-an-nsstring)

Comment: You should at least try something...

Comment: Please show things you have tried and not been able to make work.

Comment: @SeanPerry What is the point of posting failed attempts? That won't benefit anyone?

Comment: @Macmade Why would you assume that I haven't tried anything?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw your post sounded as if you had not even read the API docs. If you had said "I looked at x, y, and z and they did not work for me" then people would have a place to start. As is, your request comes off as "please do all of the work for me".

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Same as Sean Perry...

Comment: Just remember, there is ass in assignment. soo...

Comment: Attempts at this on such a basic level will generally fail - '"Damn," retorted the talking a$$ "Hell is hot!"' - and make people either annoyed or extra clever. It might also be interesting to read on [OSX/iOS dictionary censored words](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2013/07/in-apples-world-life-is-grand-as-controversial-words-are-banned-in-ios-spell-check) .. *sigh*

Comment: @JohnRiselvato Yes :) Thankyou! Lucky for me, I'm generating random 6 digit "keys" so it doesn't matter if they get something like that and I strike it down and give them a new key, because they will never know :) They are computer generated keys! Good point for future readers of this post though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `rangeOfString:` in a loop to see if you get a match, or use a regex to check for all words at once, without a loop:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"666|ass|hell|...etc."
                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                           error:&error];
NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:passcode options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, passcode.length)];
if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
    // Found a banned word.
}
```

Comment: As long as the banned terms do not contain `*`, `?` or other regex special characters...

Comment: This seems to be the fastest way! I knew RegEx would be the best route but I am very knew to RegEx so I figured I'd add it to the tags of this question anyways and I'm glad I did! Thankyou so much sir! I will mark your answer as accepted as soon as the StackOverflow timer runs down and lets me :)

Comment: @MartinR Thankyou for that note! Lucky for my my keys are only alphanumeric, but I am wondering, surely there is a way to allow it to contain these symbols too? Like backslashing or something? (Again, I am new to RegEX)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: You can simply apply `-[NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:...]` to each term.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Correct, adding a backslash would escape the reserved regex metacharacter. If you do it in code, you need to escape the slash, too (one backslash for the compiler, one backslash for the regex engine).

Comment: Correct.... until you realize that you need to match `aassss`, `h3ll`, etc,etc,etc... ... and you match list grows to be about 85MB ... ... and you assemble a regular expression that causes your app to run out of memory ...

Comment: @bbum Well, regex can help reduce the number of possibilities - for example, `[a@][5s]{2,}` will deal with all sorts of asses :-)

Comment: True enough, @dasblinkenlight, but:   aSs a-s-s a*s àśš    assssss a33 `@33` ay-ess-ess a+s+s bytha faq'haa Tarma Zok soowa Tizak Teez tina Vorig Pond CÃº bunda Gus Poto prdel reet eema chuttar ... etc ... :)  Never underestimate the creativity of your average internet commenter....

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *string = // generate the string
for(NSString *bannedTerm in bannedTerms) {
     NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:bannedTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
     if(range.location != NSNotFound) { 
          return NO; // failed check
     }
}
return YES; // passed check
```

Comment: There seems to be a `.location` missing in the code.

Comment: @MartinR thanks. I was just making that correction.